# Do you need to put canned chili sauce in the refrigerator after it is opened?

Tags: food-safety, canning, chili

New (sealed) chili sauce doesn't need to be put in the refrigerator. After unsealing, do you need to put it in the refrigerator after the lid is tightened?

Comment: Welcome to SA!  What does it say on the label about refridgeration?

Comment: Hello, there is already a similar question for hot sauce https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/58130/should-i-refrigerate-hot-sauce 
But I will also provide a more general answer.

Comment: @moscafj: they’re not necessarily the same thing.  Chili sauce could be something tomato based like from Heinz, or sugary like Thai sweet chili sauce.

Comment: @Joe ...(a) the OP can and should specify and clarify, and (b) the information in the linked Q&A probably applies anyway....but, that is why we vote.

Comment: Try double checking the label. Most containers will have a note recommends storage. I just checked my own chili sauce and the storage instructions were underneath the list of ingredients.

Answer (score 1):

It is safe to keep your chili sauce in the pantry when the package says it.
With the lower water content and due to the sauce being highly processed it's not necessary to store it in the refrigerator. Most sauces are made from vinegar with high acidity and higher salt content that prevents them from attracting bacteria etc.

But most companies recommend storing your chili or hot sauce in the refrigerator. This prevents the sauce from color changes and helps to preserve the long-term quality of the sauce.

There is no health risk, leaving the sauce in the pantry but for an optimal sauce with fresh color and taste, I would store it in the refrigerator. Also, it lasts a lot longer when stored refrigerated.

For homemade chili sauce, I found [this](https://blog.bottlestore.com/how-to-preserve-your-hot-sauce-to-increase-shelf-life/) article interesting if you would like to read more about it. But there is also already a similar thread about the storage of hot sauces under [Should I refrigerate hot sauce?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/58130/should-i-refrigerate-hot-sauce)